# How to translate curl POST to requests POST in Python?

Tags: python, curl, post, python-requests

I have curl command which I need to transfer to requests POST in Python

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"val1": -1000, "val2": 15, "val3": "20000", "val4": "22"}'
http://some-site:6000?t=1234567890
```

I tried with:

```
payload = {'val1': val1, 'val2': val2, 'val3': val3, 'val4': val4}
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
```

`r.url` returns:

```
 http://some-site:6000?t=1234567890&val1=-1000&val2=15&val3=20000&val4=22
```

However, I get `val1 is not defined` response from server. I can see in curl command that val1 and val2 are int type. Can I send with `requests` ints and strings separately or this is not the reason for this error?

Comment: You want to send a payload, not send query parameters I guess. So use `json=payload` for this purpose. `params` are the query parameters, they're added to the url that's built. I'd suggest doing some researches on HTTP and urls before.

Comment: It's a lapsus. I corrected it to `post`

Comment: I am `researching` Python. Can't learn all at once :) Step by step

Comment: @HrvojeT best way to research python is through http://www.diveintopython3.net/. or this site.

Comment: I agree, but I have to do some solutions at work, but Im not a developer. So, automating my work stuff is best way to learn. It keeps me motivated.

Comment: https://curl.trillworks.com is a site I use a lot to do exactly the things you asked. just post the curl command and it will transfer it to python code. this will be handy e.g. if you do some requests in your browser and copy the requests over the dev-tools as a curl command. you can paste these commands afterwards to curl.trillworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `requests.post(url, json=payload)`?.. `params=payload` append query string arguments and `json=payload` sends JSON as the body + content-type header

```
import requests
payload = {'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3, 'val4': 3}
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json=payload)
print(r.json())

>>> {u'args': {},
>>>  u'data': u'{"val3": 3, "val2": 2, "val1": 1, "val4": 3}',
>>>  ...
```

Comment: exactly :) it's that simple. if you have difficulties with `requests` library, it's kind of recommended to use quite a handy web-site http://httpbin.org/, that just echoes what it received.